# dom: innerHTML call is not displaying code

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I have this html:

```
<h3 id="this-is-title">This is title</h3>
<p><a name="abcde"></a></p>
<pre lang="java" class="prettyprint">

 class NeoEach {

   static <T, V, E> void Each(int limit, Iterable<T> i, Asyncc.IEacher<T, E> m, Asyncc.IEachCallback<E> f) {

     final CounterLimit c = new CounterLimit(limit);
     final ShortCircuit s = new ShortCircuit();
     final var iterator = i.iterator();
     RunEach(iterator, c, s, m, f);
     handleSameTickCall(s);
   }

 }
</pre>
```

when it's loaded as an `index.html` file, it displays like this:

[image: nh]

but when I set the innerHTML of a dom element like this:

```
     fetch('https://async-java.github.io/md/html-from-md.html')
      .then(r => {
        const el = document.getElementById('foo');
        return r.text().then(v => {
          el.innerHTML = v; // this is good
        });
      });
```

it displays like this:

[image]

I can't figure out why it's not working, anyone know why?

The HTML looks fine when I inspect the dom:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, then you're having a **div#foox** but you're trying to set the innerHTML of **#foo**.
So

```
const el = document.getElementById('foox');
```

instead of

```
const el = document.getElementById('foo');
```

**Edit**
In case you're using Google's code-prettify library, follow the HTML5 convention by wrapping a `<code>` element inside of the `<pre>` element ([GitHub - google/code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)).

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-java">...</code></pre>
```

Comment: yeah this wasn't it, I renamed the el from foo to foox, so it't the right element, not sure what's going on

Comment: If you're using React or Angular or other frameworks, you might have to sanitize the input you're trying to insert into the DOM. Also, consider "re-rendering" that might potentially override the innerHTML specified prior, if using such frameworks.